# Why the Screen didn't wake up when I call acquire in Android?

Tags: android

I am trying to wake the screen when the screen is off (dark).

I create a class like the following code:

```
public class ScreenWakeLock {

    private static PowerManager.WakeLock WakeLock;

    @SuppressLint("Wakelock")
    static void acquireCpuWakeLock(Context context) {
        Log.i("ScreenWakeLock", "acquireCpuWakeLock");
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

        WakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP,"okTag");
        WakeLock.acquire();
    }

    static void releaseCpuLock() {
        if (WakeLock != null) {
            WakeLock.release();
            WakeLock = null;
        }
    }
}
```

When the Screen is off , the App call `ScreenWakeLock.acquireCpuWakeLock(getActivity());`.

But the Screen didn't wake up. I have seen the `acquireCpuWakeLock` in the log , I am sure the function `acquireCpuWakeLock` has been called. I also add the     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />` in `Manifest.xml`.

Why the Screen didn't wake up when I call acquire in Android ?

Did I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you acquiring wake up lock after screen off? If yes then acquire wakeup onCreate() or onStart().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from the [PowerManager documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html):

> In addition, you can add two more flags, which affect behavior of the
>   screen only. These flags have no effect when combined with a
>   PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK.

Use something else instead of `PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`. Try `SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK` and see if that's good enough for your use case; if not, try `SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK`.

Comment: Thanks , it is work after change to `SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK`. And a little question. If I call `WakeLock.acquire();` for twice but `WakeLock.release();` only once. Is it effect to the phone ?

Comment: **Make sure your calls to `acquire()` and `release()` are balanced.** The worst thing you can do is accidentally (or intentionally) keep a wake lock because you will prevent the phone from sleeping and you will drain the user's battery.